# PHP Ajax MySQL Table Row Delete

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, sql-delete

I wrote the code to delete MySQL table rows. But when I click on delete icon, nothing happens. Could someone please tell me what's left in my code?

```
<?php
include_once 'include/DatabaseConnector.php';
$query1="SELECT * FROM MyTable;";
$result1=DatabaseConnector::ExecuteQueryArray($query1);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteRow(tableName,colName,id){
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "delete.php",
           data: "tableName=tableName&colName=colName&id=id",
           success: function(msg){
             alert( "Row has been updated: " + msg );
           }
    });
}
</script>

<table id="newspaper-b" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width = "100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col">Opr</th>
    <th scope="col">Flt Num</th>
    <th scope="col">From</th>
    <th scope="col"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($result1 as $row):?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['airlineName'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['flightNum'];?></td>                        <td><?php echo $row['from'];?></td>
<td>
  <div title='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(<?php echo 'flightschedule','flightNum',$row['flightNum']; ?>)'>
<img src='images/delete.png' alt='Delete' />
</div>              
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php
    /* Database connection */
    include_once 'include/DatabaseConnector.php';
    if(isset($_POST['tableName']) && isset($_POST['colName']) && isset($_POST['id'])){
        $tableName = $_POST['tableName'];
        $colName = $_POST['colName'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM '.$tableName.' WHERE '.$colName.' ="'.$id.'"';
        mysql_query($sql);
    } else { 
        echo '0'; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where does `Ajax.Request` come from? Did you make it, or is it part of a library? Also, if you're not careful, code like this could allow a user to delete any data from any table in the database.

Comment: in your ajax request  u did not mention cal type'post' or get... and in ur script try $_GET to get url params

Comment: just an observation, use some kind of restriction to execute the "delete.php" because someone can make deletes into your database, calling that file from a external form, give it the parameter and that's it.. Regards

Comment: Please look at my updated post. The only trouble I have now is the following line of code: data: "tableName=tableName&colName=colName&id=id". How to pass parameters of the function "deleteRow.php"?

Answer (score 1):

- have you checked your PHP log to see if there is an error?
- what is `Ajax.Request` ? if you are using the prototype library, where is it included in your HTML code?
- finally, are you sure your PHP code is called? (check using for instance the Web Developper Tools in Chrome browser, "Requests" tab)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on this line

```
 <div title='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(<?php echo 'flightschedule','flightNum',$row['flightNum']; ?>)'>
```

this will print

```
 <div title='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(flightscheduleflightNumid)'>
```

You have to change it to

```
  <div title='Delete' onclick='deleteRow("flightschedule","flightNum",<?php $row['flightNum']; ?>)'>
```

to work.

Best wishes

Update: For the above code to work also add

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

or load it from the internet

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js"></script>
```

to include Jquery at the header of html. I have tested its ok now.

Comment: Thank you. I changed this line, but still nothing works. Maybe there is something more which is wrong in my code?

Comment: It worked for you after the update? I can read the values normally.

Comment: Have you tested the code? P.s. You can make a good use of a javascript debugger when you are writing javascript. I use bugzilla it's a nice one plugin to firefox.

Answer (score 0):

you send not your data to the delete.php file, because in the attribute dated you seize them badly. Here is this code I have just tested him(it) and that seems to work.

***data: "tableName="+tableName+"&colName="+colName+"&id="+id+"",***

```js
function deleteRow(tableName,colName,id){
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "delete.php",
           data: "tableName="+tableName+"&colName="+colName+"&id="+id+"",
           success: function(msg){
             alert( "Row has been updated: " + msg );
           }
    });
}
```